# GLSL Shader Draws Only Black Screen LWJGL

Tags: glsl, shader, lwjgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am very new to shaders, and I got some GLSL code to compile properly (well without any compiler errors), and for some reason I keep getting a black screen. I am using LWJGL. I keep getting a black screen when I try to render a triangle, even though it should be white according to the color that I passed to the fragment shader. I've posted snippets of the code below, hopefully there's enough to figure out what the problem is.

## Fragment Shader Source Code

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
{
```

## Vertex Shader Source Code

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

## Shader Reader Code

```
        vertShaderString = shaderName + ".vert";
        fragShaderString = shaderName + ".frag";
        shader = GL20.glCreateProgram();
        vertShader = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        try{
            String temp;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(vertShaderString)));
            while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null){
                vertSource.append(temp).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();


            BufferedReader fragReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fragShaderString)));
            String otherTemp;
            while ((otherTemp = fragReader.readLine()) != null){
                fragSource.append(otherTemp).append("\n");
            }
            fragReader.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

## Shader Setup Code

```
        GL20.glShaderSource(vertShader, vertSource);
        GL20.glCompileShader(vertShader);

        if (GL20.glGetShaderi(vertShader, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE){
            System.err.println("Failed to compile vertex shader");
        }


        GL20.glShaderSource(fragShader, fragSource);
        GL20.glCompileShader(fragShader);

        if (GL20.glGetShaderi(fragShader, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE){
            System.err.println("Failed to compile fragment shader");
        }

        GL20.glAttachShader(shader, vertShader);
        GL20.glAttachShader(shader, fragShader);
        GL20.glLinkProgram(shader);
        GL20.glValidateProgram(shader);
```

## Enable and Disable Shader Code

```
public void begin(){
    GL20.glUseProgram(shader);
}

public void end(){
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);
}
```

## Render Method

```
public void render(){
        GL11.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
        shader.begin();
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
        GL11.glVertex2i(0,  0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(500, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(250, 250);
        GL11.glEnd();
        shader.end();

    }
```

Comment: You should check [`GL_LINK_STATUS`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetProgramiv.xml) as well as `GL_COMPILE_STATUS`. [glGetError](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGetError.xml) is quite useful too. Does it draw without the shader active? If not it might point to drawing outside the projection/view.

Comment: @jozxyqk it compiles just fine without the shader, but when I use the shader nothing is drawn at all. I added the flag and the glGetError() function like you said, however I am not getting any errors anywhere.

Comment: Short of the typo `{` in the fragment shader and presumably the line `fragShader = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);` just not shown I can't spot anything obvious. Does introducing a syntax error stop the shaders compiling? Have you updated your drivers recently?

Comment: Forgetting to initialize the fragment shader variable was what was causing the problem! Thanks so much!

Comment: You might want to add this as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, thanks to jozxyqk. I had forgotten to initialize the fragment shader variable.

```
fragShader = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
```

By adding this line of code the problem was solved.